# How to automatically append custom headers to all API gateway responses in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

In my AWS CDK project, I have a `RestApi` and a couple of resources with methods having `LambdaIntegration` configured for them. For all requests made to the API gateway methods, I want to append a common custom header to make sure all methods work well from my website, without CORS related problems. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean any random custom header, or are you specifically trying to fix CORS errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [enabling CORS for AWS API gateway with the AWS CDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752201/enabling-cors-for-aws-api-gateway-with-the-aws-cdk)